# MIPS: writing on file, encoding problems

Tags: mips

whenever I'm trying to write something on a file. I want the user to write the string that will be then saved into this file instead of having one previously prepared. But, when I do this, every word saved into the file ends with `^@` so my usual text editor (gedit) won't read it for encoding reasons (but that's not a problem, emacs does the work successfully) and those characters marks somehow the end of the text (even if there's other following).

How can I remove it?

```
.data
fout: .asciiz "text.txt"
buffer: .space 100
cont: .asciiz "reading file... "
stringname: .space 10
nl: .asciiz "\n"

.text 

main:

create:

#input a name
move $s6, $v0
li $v0, 8
la $a0, stringname
li $a1, 5
syscall

#open
li $v0, 13
la $a0, fout
li $a1, 9
li $a2, 0
syscall
move $s6, $v0

#write on file
li $v0, 15
move $a0, $s6
la $a1, stringname
li $a2, 5
syscall

#close
li $v0, 16
move $a0, $s6
syscall

exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Having a hardcoded character count when you write to the file doesn't seem like the best idea. Why not calculate the length of the string that has been read and use that instead?

Comment: @Michael you mean in the "input a name" part? Then I should use this value in both input and write parts, right?

Comment: No, the size you specify when you read the string is the size of the buffer, i.e. the maximum number of bytes it can hold. Bu the user might not have entered the maximum allowed number of characters, so after you've read the string you should scan through it to see how many characters it actually contains.